# Magento 2 - Price filter for configurable products based on associated simples within range

Tags: magento2, price, layered-navigation

I have a catalog with a "size" attribute, and the product price varies based on the size. On the Product List Page, I am displaying only configurable products along with the product price, indicating multiple sizes with a "+" sign.

I would like to modify the price filter logic on the Product List Page according to the following scenario:

I have a configurable product with associated simples priced at $60, $80, and $100. The minimum and maximum prices stored in the database (catalog_product_index_price) for this configurable product are $60 and $100 respectively.

[image]

Currently, if I apply a price filter on the Product List Page for a range of $65 to $85, the configurable product is not included in the results because none of min_price or max_price within that range.

Is there a way to display the configurable product if at least one of its associated simples falls within the applied price filter range? I want the price filter to consider the prices of the associated simples for configurable products.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this behavior would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!